# Why can a Range be collected into a HashMap or Vec in Rust?

Tags: rust, hashmap, iterator, vec

I recently encountered a problem while learning about iterators. I attempted to convert a list of numbers into a `Vec`, but when I changed the type to `HashMap`, no error occurred. For example:

```rust
type Test = Vec<(usize, Vec<usize>)>;
// type TestHashMap = HashMap<usize, Vec<usize>>;

...
fn make_heavy_things() -> Test {
    let x = (1..=10).map(|v| (v, vec![v])).collect();
    x
}

// x can be a HashMap or Vec depending on the return type
```

Both types seem to work without any issues, and common methods like `len()` work as expected. I'm curious about the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: Ranges implement [std::iter::iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait. Note that this will [change in Edition 2024](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3550).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can a Range be collected into a HashMap or Vec in Rust?

A range can *not* be collected to a hashmap, a hashmap needs pairs of key and value, which a range is not, your iterator is not a range it's a range mapped to a pair of `(usize, Vec<usize>)`.

> I'm curious about the reason behind this behavior.

[`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) is a generic operation, it can collect into anything implementing [the `FromIterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html), which is the case of [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E-for-Vec%3CT%3E) and [`HashMap` IFF the iterator returns pairs (2-uples) and the first element of the pair implements `Hash + Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3C(K,+V)%3E-for-HashMap%3CK,+V,+S%3E).

This provides a type-safe one-stop-shop for converting iterators to various forms, and allows for useful compositions, for instance [you can collect iterators of `Result` into a single `Result`, which will stop at the first `Result::Err` it encounters and return that, and will otherwise collect into whatevet concrete collection you specify](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA,+E%3E%3E-for-Result%3CV,+E%3E)

> I recently encountered a problem

Why is it a problem?

Comment: I think the magic lies in the `FromIterator` trait then. I assumed that modifying the iterator would result in only one desired type. I was confused by how the type could change without breaking anything. Thanks, I'll check out the reference link.